# Checking descendants of a family tree in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

How can I recursively check if X is the descendent of Y, using a recursive method descendent_of? The fact base consists of males and females, and father_of/mother_of statements.

```
/* Facts */
male(roy).
male(lee).
...
female(joy).
female(ana).
...

/* Rules */
grandmother_of(X, Z) :- 
        mother_of(X, Y), 
        (mother_of(Y, Z);
                father_of(Y, Z)).


grandfather_of(X, Z) :- 
        father_of(X, Y), 
        (mother_of(Y, Z);
                father_of(Y, Z)).


parent_of(X,Y) :-
    mother_of(X,Y);father_of(X,Y).


descendent_of(X,Y) :-
    */ Recursive method here */
```

How do I set up the stopping condition? Also, how does recursion work in prolog if functions only return boolean values?

Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because they are not functions, but "predicates", and a "predicate call" builds a whole AND-OR tree of calls (searching for a solution), where "success" is attained when all the branches under AND nodes and exactly one branch under OR nodes is labeled TRUE. A "stopping condition" happens when that is not possible: the rpedictae fails. Take this afternoon and check this [Recursion: Recursion](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch3)

Comment: There are no functions, just predicates - and predicates do not return boolean values. Predicates either succeed or fail. If they fail you don't get a result. If they succeed then prolog just moves to the next goal and continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `descendant_of(X,Y)` it should be true if `X` is descendant of `Y`. The truth value is than reursivly defined as follows:
I do here a little trick to achieve consistency with `parent_of` and introduce the predicate `ancestor_of/2` as

```
 descendent_of(X,Y) :- ancestor_of(Y,X)
```

Know `X` is ancestor of `Y` if either

1. `X` is parent of `Y` or
2. `X` is parent of `Z` and `Z` is descendant of `Y`

(1) is the base case of the recursion and (2) is the recursive definition.
Hint: You could also redefine the recursive case as:  `Z` is descendant of `Y` and `X` is parent of `Z` (Keyword tail-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

I've extended your facts to give some working data.

```
/* Facts */

male(roy).
male(lee).

female(joy).
female(ana).

parent_of(roy,joy).
parent_of(joy,ana).
parent_of(lee,ana).
```

Now we can build some rules. Let's start with `grand_parent_of/2`.

```
grand_parent_of(X,Z) :-
    parent_of(X,Y),
    parent_of(Y,Z).
```

This keeps the rules for `grand_father_of/2` and `grand_mother_of/2` rather simple.

```
grand_father_of(X,Y) :-
        male(X),
        grand_parent_of(X,Y).

grand_mother_of(X,Y) :-
        female(X),
        grand_parent_of(X,Y).
```

Now, every predicate so far the ancestor has been on the left and the descendent on the right, so to keep consistency, let's define `ancestor_of/2` first, rather than `descendent_of/2`.

```
ancestor_of(X,Y) :-
    parent_of(X,Y).

ancestor_of(X,Y) :-
    parent_of(X,Z),
    ancestor_of(Z,Y).
```

Note that the second predicate is recursive.

Now we can easily define `descendent_of/2` simply in terms of `ancestor_of/2`.

```
descendent_of(X,Y) :-
        ancestor_of(Y,X).
```

Here are the results of running the following query and asking prolog to keep giving me results.

```
?- descendent_of(X,Y).
X = joy,
Y = roy ;
X = ana,
Y = joy ;
X = ana,
Y = lee ;
X = ana,
Y = roy ;
false.
```